# How can I insert a scrollbar in jquery jtable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

I am using the great jquery plugin [jtable](http://www.jtable.org). 
But I can't find any examples showing a vertical scrollbar.

I tried setting a height and overflow.auto on the div that contains it - the scrollbar then scrolls the whole table including header - I only want to scroll the rows not the header and not the footer.

Has anyone found a way to do this?

A solution that works some way is inserting:

```
$('.jtable').wrap('<div class="jtable-main-container scroll-content" />');
```

and

```
.scroll-content {
     overflow-y: auto;
    width:100%;
 }
div.jtable-main-container {
  height:100%;
}
```

And setting height on the div.
However it also scrolls the table header - but it is better than scrolling the whole jtable - I tried to make a solution where jtable generates 2 tables - one with header and one with body but the header gets out of sync.

see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/j5Q4L/3/

Comment: Have you got an answer to this question?Then plz do share...because iam also facing the same issue... :(

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.jtable').wrap('<div class="jtable-main-container scroll-content" />');    
and

.scroll-content {
     overflow-y: auto;
    width:100%;
 }
div.jtable-main-container {
  height:100%;
}
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: This did it for me! I had to set the .jtable-main-container height to %85 percent though, to avoid 3 scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <style type="text/css">
        #StudentTableContainer {
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }

            #StudentTableContainer tbody, .jtable tbody {
                height: 100px;
                overflow-y: auto;
                display: block;
            }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
                //...
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="StudentTableContainer" class="jtable"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I do get a scroll bar for the tbody but it works a bit strange. I have 4 columns and they are now fitted inside the first column with a scrollbar. I tried setting width:100% but no effect. And it does not seem to do anything in IE only firefox - any ideas?

Comment: @Rune Andersen: can u add this task in http://jsfiddle.net/ with some static data so that i can fix this bug.

Comment: @RuneAndersen you have a solution for the footer? how to make tbody scrollable only?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to css

```
table.jtable{
overflow-y: scroll;
display:block;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Or modify your jsfiddle css , instead of verflow-y: auto; Add overflow-y: scroll;